# Ubuntu 16.04 Fresh Install, headphones not detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I had a working copy of Ubuntu 16 for a while which suddenly decided it didn't want to play audio. After following this forum like a hawk and trying absolutely everything I figured it may be a good time for a fresh install.

I have now formatted the drive, installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 16 and I have no audio in the headphones.

When I plug the headphones in they are not detected, now I have seen on the forums somebody suggesting to do this to set Element Speaker in a config file to On, when I do this it in fact detects headphones plugged in but only outputs sound via the laptops speakers.

I am using a DellXPS 15 9550

ALSA Info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ff9c1ae35e5cc00282fe937713af8e0afb2440c1

I have typed alasmixer into terminal and unmuted headphones and ensured the driver is selected, that has made no difference.

```
anthony@LPT-0112:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1c5c:1284
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
0a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15b5
```